# How to decode a json with a variable property type

Tags: elm

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "level": 1,
            "displayValue": "das",
            "dataValue": "das"
        },
        {
            "level": 2,
            "displayValue": "das",
            "dataValue": {
                "name": "some name",
                "scope": "some scope"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And the following types:

```
type alias Item = 
    { level: Int
    , displayValue: String
    , dataValue: DataValue
    }

type alias KeyValue =
    { name: String
    , scope: String
    }

type DataValue
    = Value String
    | Key KeyValue
```

How would I write a decoder for the dataValue property since it can be of two completly different types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`oneOf`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#oneOf):

```elm
import Json.Decode as JD

dataValueDecoder : JD.Decoder DataValue
dataValueDecoder =
    JD.oneOf
        [ JD.map Value JD.string 
        , JD.map Key keyValueDecoder
        ]

keyValueDecoder : JD.Decoder KeyValue
keyValueDecoder =
    JD.map2 KeyValue
        (JD.field "name" JD.string)
        (JD.field "scope" JD.string)
```